# DJANGO how to make filter to show all objects in model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-filter

How to change my code so it would show all products in my *View*? Now it shows only these determined by filters.

Also how to make "neutral" option in filters so i can filter by only one category (in case of picking both 'neutrals' it will show all products).

Please see my code below:

```
> class ShopView(View):
>     def get(self, request):
>         order = request.GET.get('order', 'name')
>         products, search_form = self.search_product(request)
>         products = products.order_by(order)
>         return render(request, 'shop.html', {'products':products, 'search_form':search_form})
> 
>     def search_product(self, request):
>         search_form = FilterProductForm(request.GET)
>         search_form.is_valid()
>         shape = search_form.cleaned_data.get('shape')
>         material = search_form.cleaned_data.get('material')
>         queryset = Product.objects.all()
>         filters = Q()
>         if shape:
>             filters.add(Q(shape__in=shape), Q.AND)
>         if material:
>             filters.add(Q(material__in=material), Q.OR)
>         return queryset.filter(filters), search_form
```

and HTML:
'''

```
{%  block content %}
{% for product in products %}
<li>
<a href="{% url 'product_detail' product.id %}">
{{ product.name }}
</a>
</li>
{% endfor %}
<label>
<form>
{{ search_form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Szukaj">
</form>
<a href="?order=price">Price ascending</a><br>
<a href="?order=-price">Price descending</a>
{%  endblock %}
```

'''

Comment: products = Products.objects.all()

Comment: but i would like to save my filters but add option "see all"

Comment: Not sure if I get want you want, but it sound like you need to user one filtered and one unfiltered query.

Comment: now my page shows only products determined by these to filters (material and shape). i want two things:
-to show all products before usage of filters on the View,
-to make option "all" to show all material or shapes,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will always have filtered queryset, because you are passing default parameter to the `get`. Like here:

```
shape = search_form.cleaned_data.get('shape',[0,1,2])
material = search_form.cleaned_data.get('material',[0,1,2,3])
```

Do not provide default parameter(its `None` by default):

```
shape = search_form.cleaned_data.get('shape')
material = search_form.cleaned_data.get('material')
```

Now, you have to check if there are filters provided. If not, simply return `Product.objects.all()`

```
queryset = Product.objects.all()
filters = Q()
if shape:
    filters.add(Q(shape__in=shape), Q.AND)
if material:
    filters.add(Q(material__in=material), Q.AND)

return queryset.filter(filters)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216655/discussion-on-answer-by-mikolaj-rutecki-django-how-to-make-filter-to-show-all-ob).